# Show the parent taxonomy by creating shortcode in woocommerce?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, taxonomy, archives

How would I create a shortcode to show the parent taxonomy in woocommerce?

My product categories should be like:

- Food

*-- Fruits*

--- Healthy Fruits
--- Organic Fruits

*-- Meat*

--- Pork
--- Lamb
--- Beef

For example, I would like to display the taxonomy name "Fruits" in somewhere when user at the "Healthy Fruits" product archive page.

Comment: do you mean automatically add the shortcode?

Comment: no gael, I want to manually type the shortcode on "Healthy Fruits" product archive page

Answer (score 0):

The Shortcode to display products in "Fruits" category when user is on another page or archive... is:

```
[products category="fruits"]
```

As far as I know there is no shortcode to display the parent category products without specifying the given category slug.

For your 2nd example you will have to call it in your sub category "Pork"

`[products category="meat"]`

and so on for each category.

You can find WooCommerce shortcodes here:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: Thanks gael, this is just my example. In fact I want it to show the parent category but not just hard code it.

Comment: For example, I would like to display "Fruits" when user at the "Healthy Fruits" product archive page.  To display "Meat" when user at the "Pork" product archive.

Comment: Thanks gael, but hardcode is not preferred since there will be tons of categories. Therefore, I would like to know how to make a custom shortcode to my question.

Answer (score -1):

Here is shortcode function that will display parent category

```
// Register the shortcode
function display_parent_taxonomy_shortcode() {
    add_shortcode('parent_taxonomy', 'get_parent_taxonomy');
}
add_action('init', 'display_parent_taxonomy_shortcode');

// Callback function for the shortcode
function get_parent_taxonomy() {
    // Check if we are on a product category archive page
    if (is_product_category()) {
        global $wp_query;

        // Get the current category object
        $category = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

        // Get the parent category ID
        $parent_id = $category->parent;

        // If the parent ID is greater than 0, get the parent category
        if ($parent_id > 0) {
            $parent_category = get_term($parent_id, 'product_cat');
            $parent_name = $parent_category->name;

            // Return the parent category name
            return $parent_name;
        }
    }

    // If not on a product category archive page or parent category not found, return an empty string
    return '';
}
```

Now insert the [parent_taxonomy] shortcode in your desired location

Reference:
https://techvila.com/shortcode-to-show-the-parent-taxonomy-in-woocommerce/